# Liberar acesso a uma página com tempo definido

Tags: html5

Olá.
Sou novo em criação de sites e preciso de ajuda com a seguinte situação:
Um cliente solicitou a seguinte situação:
Na página "Principais Clientes" deve haver uma maneira de liberar um acesso temporário para quem queira ver o portfólio que contém os produtos destes "Principais Clientes" e que este acesso tenha uma duração de 5 dias. 
A solução que encontrei foi de que nessa página tenha um formulário onde insiram CNPJ e e-mail para que haja este controle de acesso. Pensei em após obter as informações no formulário enviar um link no e-mail e a pessoa poder acessar a página em questão somente nos 5 dias como informado acima e após isso o link não funcionar mais.

A minha dúvida é: Qual caminho devo seguir?

Como informei eu sou novo nessa área. Eu sei que vai precisar de BD, mas não sei nem por onde começar e o que usar.

Alguém poderia dar uma luz?? - A página com formulário já está pronta.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Vc usa php ou oq?

Comment: html5+css+bootstrap

Comment: Sem linguagem backend vc não vai conseguir fazer nada, nem enviar email.

Comment: Só preciso de uma espécie de "passo-a-passo" do que fazer para conseguir atingir o objetivo. Aí eu corro atrás de como fazer, nem q tenha que aprender alguma linguagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você já disse que tem um formulário, então vou listar um passo-a-passo simples sem entrar em detalhes, isso você encontra com facilidade aqui no SOpt ou caso tenha dúvidas poderá fazer novas perguntas específicas. Vou fazer usando PHP que é o mais comum.

**1º. Banco de dados**

Primeiro você deve criar um banco de dados (pode ser MySQL, que é bem comum) com uma tabela com 5 colunas:

- `id`: é a coluna primária de auto-incremento, que apenas *vai contando* o número de registros à medida em que eles são inseridos na tabela.
- `email`: onde será armazenado o email do usuário. (tipo *varchar*)
- `CNPJ`: onde será armazenado o CNPJ do usuário. (tipo *varchar*)
- `token`: onde será armazenado o *token* (um tipo de sequência única randômica para cada registro, como se fosse uma senha, ex.: `Ah2bd5h8Hjs`). O próprio PHP tem recurso nativo para gerar isso. (tipo *varchar*)
- `dia`: nesse campo você pode armazenar o dia em que o usuário se cadastrou, para depois verificar se ele tem mais de 5 dias. (tipo *date* ou *datetime*)

**2º. Enviar o formulário para um arquivo PHP**

Depois de preenchido o formulário, você vai submetê-lo (enviar) para um arquivo PHP (`nome_do_arquivo.php`) via POST (pode inclusive usar Ajax). Esse arquivo PHP irá receber os campos do formulário (email e CNPJ) e irá gravar no BD as respectivas informações (`email`, `CNPJ`, `token` e `dia`). Antes de gravar no BD, você deve gerar o *token* e pegar a data atual (o email e o CNPJ já vem do formulário).

Após gravar os dados no BD, você vai enviar uma mensagem de email para o usuário com um link contendo o email e o *token*, neste modelo:

```
http://seusite.com.br/pagina.php?email=email_do_usuario&token=token_que_foi_gerado
```

**3º. Validando**

O usuário irá receber a mensagem com o link. Ao clicar ele será redirecionado ao seu site conforme o link. Na página PHP para onde o link leva, você irá pegar os parâmetros "email" e "token" que estão na URL do link e consultar no BD se os dois pertencem ao mesmo registro. Caso haja alguma divergência, significa que o link é inválido, aí você pode exibir uma mensagem "*link inválido*" ou redirecionar (isso depende da sua escolha).

Caso a consulta ao BD retorne que o "email" e o "token" estão corretos, você faz a última verificação: ver se já se passaram 5 dias. Para isso você vai usar o valor do campo `dia` retornado da consulta ao BD. Para isso você terá que usar comparação entre datas, ver se o dia que está na tabela do BD tem mais de 5 dias da data atual. Caso seja maior, significa que já se passaram 5 dias e você pode exibir uma mensagem "*Período esgotado*" ou redirecionar (isso a seu critério). Mas caso na comparação das datas a diferença seja de até 5 dias, significa que está tudo OK e o usuário pode prosseguir.

**Edit**: Acima citei fazer a validação em 2 etapas. Mas você pode e até melhor fazer em 1 etapa. Na mesma consulta ao BD, verifica de uma só vez se o *email*, *token* e o *dia* conferem e tem menos de 5 dias.

**Resumindo:**

O esquema acima é apenas um apanhado superficial, e em alguns pontos irá envolver verificação de dados etc., mas não é tão complicado. Acredito que mesmo iniciantes, com um pouco de pesquisa e esforço, conseguirá fazer. Vá passo-a-passo, testando cada passo até chegar ao ponto final.

```
  ENVIO DO FORM PARA O PHP                     VALIDAÇÃO DO LINK
            ↓                                          ↓
    validar email e CNPJ                     captura os parâmetros
    (ver se são válidos)                    "email" e "token" da URL
      ↓            ↓                                   ↓
   não são      válidos                          consulta o BD
   válidos         ↓                              ↓         ↓
      ↓            ↓                          inválidos  válidos
 retorna erro      ↓                           ↓              ↓
(não faz nada)     ↓                      retorna erro  verifica o dia
                   ↓                     (não faz nada)  ↓          ↓
      gerar token e pegar data                           ↓          ↓
                   ↓                                 tem mais de  tem menos
             gravar no BD                              5 dias     de 5 dias
                   ↓                                     ↓          ↓
         enviar email com link                      retorna erro   acesso
            para o usuário                          (nega acesso)  liberado
                   ↓
                  FIM
         (exibe uma mensagem que
             deu tudo certo)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo pela explicação... Está tudo muito claro... Agora é pesquisar e testar até conseguir... vlw...

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente tu vai precisar escolher uma de linguagem *backend* para implementar no projeto.

Após fazer isso, para controlar esse acesso de 5 dias, podes fazer o seguinte:

Crie 2 campos a mais na tabela, um campo para detectar se o usuário está ativo ou não, ou seja, se ainda não esgotou os 5 dias dele e um campo para armazenar a data de quando ele fez o cadastro. Então sempre que ele logar, tu compara a data do cadastro com a data atual, e se a diferença entre elas for maior do que 5, tu deixa o campo que mencionei antes como desativado.